# Vernam cipher trouble

Tags: encryption

i got open text 414243( all in hex format) encrypted in 6B7F7C.
Is it somehow possible to find ouy key? And how can i find open text if encrypted text is 496B4D.
Would appreciate any information,there is not so many about this cipher on the Internet. Thank you!

Comment: In case of founding open text if encrypted text is 496B4D,the key is the same as was in previous example ( 414243 encrypted into 6B7F7C)

Comment: The encryption is done through `XOR`? If yes, then a simple `XOR` between plaintext and ciphertext gives the key. And there are plenty of things on this cipher on the internet.

Comment: @corpsfini yes it's XOR. Would you please give me some links where I can see how to find key, if i have encrypted and open text.

Comment: You'd first decode the hexadecimal pairs into a byte array, and then XOR them one by one. You can also write out the binary values instead of hexadecimal values and then perform the XOR yourself.

Comment: @Guest15423 You are basically asking how to do `XOR` of values. Since you didn't specify a programming language, and that the values are small, you can do it by hand and I suggest you do by writing the binary representation as Maarten Bodewes said and you XOR bit by bit using the rules that you can find on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the text `ABC` in hex is `414243` and this has been encrypted with an `X` key that turns it into `6B7F7C`. In order to reveal the key we do `414243 XOR 6B7F7C` and the output will be the key. `2a3d3f` is the key, now we can `XOR` the key with the last encrypted text `496B4D`to reveal what it means. In this case the result of the bitwise operation results in `635672`. This is still in hex so if we translate into `ASCII` we get `cVr`.

I hope everything is clear!